# How do i solve this to find PMT?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, finance

I know this may seem like a stupid question but i've been up late working on this math assignment and this question just isn't working when i transpose it.

So this is the formula to find Present Value (PV) and I'm rearranging it to find PMT.

$$PV = PMT  - \frac{1-(1 + i/k)^{-n} } {i/k}$$

PV = 429000
K = 12
N = 300
i = 5.11

Can someone link me to an annuity calculator!

Comment: So basically you're trying to find the monthly payment(PMT) of an annuity is it ?

Comment: is the edit correct?

Comment: Yes I am trying to find the monthly payment using annuity!

Comment: You have to use calculator to simplify the expressions, these finance calculations are difficult to carry out without calculator. Are you allowed to use calculator ?

Comment: Wait I am allowed to use a finance calculator but I need to show my steps of how I got to it.

Comment: Oh yes that can be done :  $PV = PMT\times \left(\dfrac{1-\left(1+\dfrac{i}{k}\right)^{-n}}{\dfrac{i}{k}}\right)$

Comment: thats your formula, eh ?

Comment: Yes that's my formula!

Comment: Okay, its just algebra I guess... see the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$PV = PMT\times \left(\dfrac{1-\left(1+\dfrac{i}{k}\right)^{-n}}{\dfrac{i}{k}}\right)$

Your goal is to isolate $PMT$, so simply divide  :

$\dfrac{PV}{\left(\dfrac{1-\left(1+\dfrac{i}{k}\right)^{-n}}{\dfrac{i}{k}}\right)} = PMT$

Rearranging a bit you would get :

$\boxed{\dfrac{PV\times \dfrac{i}{k}}{1-\left(1+\dfrac{i}{k}\right)^{-n}} = PMT}$

Plugin the given values and evaluate !

Comment: Thanks man you're the best!

Comment: you're welcome :) its a good idea to verify your work with wolfram :  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28429000*%280.0511%2F12%29%29%2F%281-%281%2B0.0511%2F12%29%5E%28-300%29%29